# Splitting a text in one column into many columns for each row

Tags: r, stringr

I have the following dataset:

```
Class      Range      Value
A          6 - 8      19
B          1 - 3      14
C          5 - 16     10
D          4 - 7      5
```

I want to split the range for each class into two columns. To do that, I used the function `str_split_fixed` as the following:

```
merge(data, str_split_fixed(data[, 2], " - ", 2))
```

and I even tried:

```
merge(data, str_split_fixed(data$Range, " - ", 2))
```

But both of them give me the following results:

```
Class      Range      Value    V1     V2
A          6 - 8      19       6      8
B          1 - 3      14       6      8
C          5 - 16     10       6      8
D          4 - 7      5        6      8
```

My question is, why does it repeat the first range for the rest of the classes? Can someone help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The output of `str_split_fixed` is a two column `matrix` (no dimnames), and when we do a `merge` with out specifying the column name, it does a cross join.  Instead of `merge`, we could use a `cbind` or assign to two columns

```
data[c('V1', 'V2')] <- str_split_fixed(data[, 2], " - ", 2)
```

NOTE: The output of `str_split` are elements with `character` type.  It may need to converted to `numeric`

---

An easier option is `separate`

```
library(tidyverse)
data %>%
    separate(Range, into = c("V1", "V2"), convert = TRUE)
#   Class V1 V2 Value
#1     A  6  8    19
#2     B  1  3    14
#3     C  5 16    10
#4     D  4  7     5
```

---